# Using sed in Windows with simple regular expression in file path

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I use a simple regular expression in file path when calling this sed command:

```
sed -i "s/showIntro.*/showIntro\t= false/" "c:\me\test_*\config.ini"
```

where `*` matches the suffix of a folder `test_` in the path. (e.g. test_1.0, test_2.0, etc)

But for some reason the sed gives me an error:

```
sed: c:\me\test_*\config.ini: Invalid argument
```

I tried using with and without the quotes but it makes no difference.

Any idea what should I change here?

Thanks!

Comment: On my computer there is difference if I write first as you `"c:\me\test_*\config.ini"` and then in a different way: `c:\me/test_*/config.ini` or `/c/me/test_*/config.ini` (no double quotes!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
FORFILES /M c:\me\test_*\config.ini /C "sed -i ^0x22s/showIntro.*/showIntro\t= false/^0x22 ^0x22@path^0x22"
```